# Allow Wake on LAN only for specific devices

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, sleep, wake-on-lan

Is it possible to allow Wake-on-LAN (WoL) only for specific devices?

At the moment I got Plex (running Windows 10 Pro) and the PC automatically wakes up, as soon as I try to access Plex on my TV. This is how I want it, but somehow there are other devices on the network irregularly waking up my PC (I dont know what). Is it possible to prevent this through MAC/IP Filters? Are there other ways?

Comment: Does the motherboard also have Wake on Network Activity? Wake-on-LAN should only activate when it receives a magic packet.

Comment: Your question's title looks _really_ strange to me.

Comment: @UweKeim I dont know what happend there, I corrected it.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Yes, I think its called Wake on pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

This isnt WOL that you're talking about I suspect, if you have a CIFS/SMB share (a "shared folder") setup then other devices searching for network peers can sometimes wake the machine from sleep. Also devices searching for UPnP players may be touching base with Plex and waking it.

Normally plex is considered as a server application and is deployed on an always on machine.

Comment: That is whats happening, and it would be great if I could filter this before waking the pc. The simplest idea would be to only allow my TV to wake plex. But it would also be suitable if I could set, that it only wakes, when accessed on port xyz.

Comment: All devices will call to the same port. That won't help you. Are you sure the PC is actually asleep or are the drives just spun down?

Comment: Yes the PC is asleep, actually my PC is waking up through Wake on pattern match, that enables the pc if someone on the network tries to connect to my pc.

Comment: Ok then, the NIC is watching for anything ARPing for it, then waking. Its the NIC itself doing this, not the CPU, so it doesnt have the ability to filter.What you could do is change to magic packet then you'd use your phone to trigger a wake with a widget whenever you need it.